# CodeIgniter POST call Output Status : 303 See Other

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, post, codeigniter-3

I have been trying to make a POST call in Codeigniter for past 3 days but unable to get POST Data.

I initially had it in table format, but on exploring, I found that getting input fields from table in CodeIgniter has posed many errors. SO today I tried it with normal input elements. I am still unable to retrieve the POST data.

Page URL formed :
http://localhost/myproject/set-schedule

Form :

```
<?= form_open('set-schedule') ?>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Select Date: </label>
                  <?php
                        $formData = "";
                        if(isset($_GET['date'])) {
                          $formData = $this->schedule_model->get_data($_GET['date']);
                          echo "<input type=\"text\" class=\"date-picker\" id=\"add_date\" value=" . $_GET['date'] ."></input>";
                        } else {
                          echo "<input type=\"text\" class=\"date-picker\" id=\"add_date\"></input>";
                        }
                  ?>
              </div>

                <div class="div-table">
                   <div class="div-table-row">
                      <div class="div-table-col heading" align="center">DATE</div>
                      <div  class="div-table-col heading">Head1</div>
                      <div  class="div-table-col heading">Head2</div>
                      <div  class="div-table-col heading">Head3</div>
                      <div  class="div-table-col heading">Head4</div>
                   </div>

                  <?php for ($row = 1; $row <= 7; $row ++) { ?>
                        <div class="div-table-row" id="form_data_custom">
                          <div class="div-table-col" align="center">
                            <?php echo "<input type='text' class='form-group' name='date_" . $row . "' placeholder='Enter DATE' readonly></input>"; ?>
                          </div>
                          <div class="div-table-col" align="center">
                            <?php echo "<input type='text' class='form-group' name='a_" . $row . "' placeholder='Enter Entry A'></input>"; ?>
                          </div>
                          <div class="div-table-col" align="center">
                            <?php echo "<input type='text' class='form-group' name='b_" . $row . "' placeholder='Enter Entry B'></input>"; ?>
                          </div>
                          <div class="div-table-col" align="center">
                            <?php echo "<input type='text'  class='form-group' name='c_" . $row . "' placeholder='Enter Entry C'></input>"; ?>
                          </div>
                          <div class="div-table-col" align="center">
                            <?php echo "<input type='text' class='form-group' name='d_" . $row . "' placeholder='Enter Entry D'></input>"; ?>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                  <?php } ?>

              </div>
              <div class="form-group text-right">
                <input type="submit" class="form-group btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Submit"> Add/Update
                </input>
              </div>

            </form>
```

Routes :

```
$route['set-schedule'] = 'schedule/set';
```

Controller (schedule.php):

```
    public function set()
    {
        var_dump('HERE');

        // create the data object
        $data = new stdClass();

        // load form helper and validation library
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');


        $form_data = $this->input->post();
        echo json_encode($_POST);
        echo json_encode("----");
        echo json_encode($form_data);

        ........
}
```

> Getting all POST Data as NULL

Please guide on where I might be going wrong. Thanks

Comment: Also I can see the data being submitted in chrome debugger for the post call, under "Form Data"

Comment: have u tried like this  print_r($this->input->post());

Comment: USE THIS <?php echo form_open('set-schedule') ?> INSTEAD OF <?= form_open('set-schedule') ?>

Comment: Why? What is the issue with `<?=` @DanishAli

Comment: Hi pradeep, print_r gives the same. While adding die(var_dump($_POST)) at the top of index.php I can see my POST data. But not in controller

Comment: @danish : Still makes no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Have you tried this :**

use this line of code

```
     public function set()
     {
        var_dump($this->input->post());
        /*--OR---*/
        var_dump($_REQUEST);
         /*--OR---*/
        print_r($this->input->post());
        die;
     }
```

Comment: Getting empty : string(8) "HERE" array(0) { } array(0) { } Array ( ) []

Comment: print anything and die in your controller to check the url is working

Comment: This is weird. When I add die, I can see the data now ! Why is that. Does this means I am getting data but only unable to print it,

Comment: you have to use die to prevent the further processing of the page

Comment: ok.so I am assuming the data is processing fine. I have been needlessly bumping head on this one. Thanks for help. Will try process further

Comment: my pleasur happy coding

Comment: @zeetit add name attribute in all input fields to get your form data

Comment: @danish : thanks Danish. Yes I made sure to have the name attribute to all the fields.